# Passando dados para outra página

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

preciso de uma ajuda de vocês,

Eu tenho dois formulários,
Formulario 1
Formulario 2

no `Formulario 1` eu tenho um campo de data, ao preencher esse campo de data eu quero que ele copie para o `Formulario 2` sem eu precisar digitar, é possivel fazer isso utilizando `JAVASCRIPT`?

eu consigo puxar os dados do outro form atraves desta linha de código

```
Service
    var dia1Service = new Basics.Services.Services.Formulario.Dia1Service();

Form
   var dia1 = dia1Service.getByCadastroId(id);
```

aqui abaixo está a minha validação com JAVASCRIPT:

```
function validaDataDois(campo, valor) {
        var variavelBasais = @(dadosBasais.isubrar);
        var variavelDia1 = @(dia1.isubrd1);

        var date = new Date(valor.split('/').reverse().join('/'));

        var dataAlta = $('[name="dtirr"]').val();
        var dataAltaValida = new Date(dataAlta.split('/').reverse().join('/'));


        var dateDia1 = '@(dia1 != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dia1.dtd1) ? Convert.ToDateTime(dia1.dtd1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty)'
        var dateDia1Valid = new Date(dateDia1.split('/').reverse().join('/'));

        var dataRandomizado = '@Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.datarandomizacao.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")';
        var dataRando = new Date(dataRandomizado.split('/').reverse().join('/'));

        if (!isValidDate(valor)) {
            $('#dtirr-msg').show();
            $('#dtirr-msg').text('Data inválida: ' + dataAlta);
            $('[name="dtirr"]').val('');
        }else if(variavelBasais == "1"){
            if(dataAltaValida < dataRando){
                $('#dtirr-msg').show();
                $('#dtirr-msg').text('A data informada está menor que a data de randomização: ' + dataRandomizado);
                $('[name="dtirr"]').val('');
            }
        }else if(variavelDia1 == "1"){
// A DATA TEM QUE APARECER NESSE CAMPO ABAIXO
            $('[name="dtirr"]').val();
        }
        else {
            $('#dtirr-msg').hide();
            $('.valida_btn').prop('disabled', false).attr('disabled');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eles serão em páginas separadas ou na mesma página?

Comment: Paginas separadas, eu vi aqui que da pra usar o paramentro @Model.xxx algo do tipo para puxar os dados

Comment: Sim tem que ser em javascript, eu editei o topico mostrando a linha e codigo que uso para puxar os dados do outro formulario

Comment: Eu peguei a seguinte explicação com um amigo meu só que não entendi muito bem

"Quando você usa o "@Model.xxx" você tá passando por Model
Da outra forma você tem que mudar de página...passando os parâmetros na url"

Comment: Se vai ter mudança de página, o ideal é fazer isso no servidor. Até tem como fazer com javascript no client, usando localStorage, mas nesse caso o mais recomendado é usar o C#.

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo Poderia explicar melhor o que deseja? Quer passar um dado de um formulário para o outro? Se sim, como estão os dois fomulários? Quer fazer isso no client ou no server? Os formulários são seguidos ou para chegar no segundo você deverá passar por diversas telas?

Comment: Quer que vá quando? No `submit` do formulário 1? Se for, pode colocar na `ViewBag` não?

Comment: Seguinte são dois formularios separados um do outro, quando eu entrar no formulario 2 ele vai carregar a data do formulario 1, sem eu precisar digitar ela novamente o 'ViewBag' não está puxando o dado

Comment: vou editar o topico com a minha validação em javascript

Comment: @jbueno Porque é a forma mais simples. Utilizando localStorage você pode ter problemas com browsers antigos. É bem mais fácil utilizar uma linguagem server side para pegar o GET ou POST de um formulário do que fazer uma gambiarra com uma sessão (localStorage) para usar apenas para replicar uma informação.

Comment: Coloquei um comentário no campo da validação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um alternativa usando apenas JavaScript é salvar o valor no *localStorage/sessionStorage* e quando for abrir a outra página procurar por este valor.

No **primeiro formulário** - supondo que a transição vai ocorrer após um clique num botão - salve valor no *localStorage*.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('algumaDataEspecial', valorDaDataEspecial);
});
```

No segundo formulário você procura por este valor no *localStorage* e, se existir, coloca o valor no input

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('algumaDataEspecial')){            
        var data = localStorage.getItem('algumaDataEspecial');
        //Colocar o valor no input, ou seja lá o que quer fazer
        localStorage.removeItem('algumaDataEspecial');
    }
});
```

Comment: não funcionuou, você viu o script que postei no post ?